# Column Alignment In Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock

Is there a better way to align the columns? When the text changes the 3 and 4 columns move all over the place. I have tried setting Width to * and auto, but nothing seems to work.

```
<ListBox Height="Auto" BorderThickness="0" MouseDoubleClick="OnMouseDoubleClick" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Results}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Entry, Mode=TwoWay}" AlternationCount="2">              
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="150"></ColumnDefinition>
               <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="150"></ColumnDefinition>
               <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="150"></ColumnDefinition>
               <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Sagoe UI" FontSize="14" 
                       Text="{Binding FullName}" Padding="2"  />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="Sagoe UI" FontSize="14" 
                       Text="{Binding Company}" Padding="2" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" FontFamily="Sagoe UI" FontSize="14" 
                       Text="{Binding BusinessPhone}" Padding="2" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" FontFamily="Sagoe UI" FontSize="14" 
                       Text="{Binding EmailAddress}" Padding="2" >  
            </TextBlock>
         </Grid>                        
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Seems like you are trying to create your own `ListView` with `GridView`. Look at this example, it might be what you need: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/gridview-in-wpf/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with setting [Grid.IsSharedSizeScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope.aspx) on the ListBox and setting unique [SharedSizeGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup.aspx) on every grid column. This should align your columns.

```
<ListBox Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" Height="Auto" BorderThickness="0" MouseDoubleClick="OnMouseDoubleClick" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Results}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Entry, Mode=TwoWay}" AlternationCount="2">              
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="C"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="D"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Sagoe UI" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding FullName}" Padding="2"  />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="Sagoe UI" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Company}" Padding="2" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" FontFamily="Sagoe UI" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding BusinessPhone}" Padding="2" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" FontFamily="Sagoe UI" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding EmailAddress}" Padding="2" >  
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>                        
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```